# Yarn run through exec.CommandContext with context.WithTimeout does not work when setting cmd.Stdout & cmd.Stderr

Tags: go, hadoop-yarn

I am triggering `yarn install` command and using custom LogWriter to log yarn stdout & stderr to Go respectively. It should terminated/interrupted after 60 seconds. But it is continuing until completed. It only works if I comment cmd.Stdout & cmd.Stderr.

```
func main() {

  ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.TODO(), 60*time.Second)
  defer cancel()

  cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "yarn", "install")
  cmd.Dir := "/project/"
  cmd.Stdout = LogWriter{ctx: ctx}
  cmd.Stderr = LogWriter{ctx: ctx}
  if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    // yarn install command should be interrupted after 60 sec
    os.Exit(1)
  }

  os.Exit(0)
}
```

The LogWriter implementation:

```
// LogWriter Custom Log output type that includes a context for logging
type LogWriter struct {
    ctx context.Context
}

func (c LogWriter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(bytes.NewReader(p))

    logging.Infof(c.ctx, string(p))

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error scanning input: %v", err)
    }
    return len(p), nil
}
```

Comment: If yarn is spawning a sub process, the context is not going to signal the right process. Try setting stdout and stderr to `os.Stdout` and `os.Stderr`

Comment: @JimB it works if I use `os.Stdout` and `os.Stderr`. But I want to use my own custom LogWriter. I am wondering, why using custom LogWriter has anything to do with context cancellation.

Comment: It works only in the sense that you are not waiting to finishing shuttling data from the pipes into your logger, but the subprocess is still continuing on. How to handle this depends on what yarn does, you could try assigning a different `Cancel` func to send SIGHUP or SIGTERM to see if that propagates to the subprocess. If terminating the subprocess is not important, you could assign your own pipes to get the output for the logger and just not block on their closing.

Comment: @JimB, it might be helpful if you explain it through some code example post as a potential answer.